# GCC ignoring a library when run from my makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, static-libraries, mingw-w64

I made my own library, called j (inventively).
I placed the library in the directory of my makefile.
To show my layout, here's verbatim what `ls -R` spits out:

```
a.exe  header  libj.a  makefile  src

./header:
jlib

./header/jlib:
dstring.h  eio.h

./src:
main.c  main.d  main.o
```

When I run `gcc src/main.c -static -L. -lj -Iheader -std=c11` it links just fine! However when I run what I think is the equivalent from my makefile, `ld` complains of missing symbols...
I'm on Windows with Mingw-w64.

Here's my makefile:

```
target := librarytest.exe
lflags := -static -L. -lj
cflags := -std=c11 -g -Iheader -Wall
cc := C:\MinGW\bin\gcc

srcfiles := $(wildcard src/*.c)
hdrfiles := $(wildcard header/*)

objfiles := $(srcfiles:.c=.o)
dependencies := $(srcfiles:.c=.d)

build: $(target)

$(target): $(objfiles)
    $(cc) -o $(target) $(objfiles) $(lflags)

.c.o:
    $(cc) $(cflags) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@


-include $(dependencies)
```

Here's the exact error:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc -std=c11 -g -Iheader -Wall -MMD -MP -c src/main.c -o src/main.o
src/main.c: In function 'main':
src/main.c:8:14: warning: variable 'paramSeed' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  const char* paramSeed = NULL;
              ^
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc -o librarytest.exe src/main.o -static -L. -lj
src/main.o: In function `main':
F:\school\csci440\homework1/src/main.c:56: undefined reference to `String_wrap_d'
F:\school\csci440\homework1/src/main.c:57: undefined reference to `String_touint'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:15: recipe for target 'librarytest.exe' failed
mingw32-make: *** [librarytest.exe] Error 1
```

Here's the nm for libj.a

```
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U __imp___iob_func
                 U fprintf
                 U free
                 U malloc
                 U memcpy
                 U printf
                 U realloc
                 U sscanf
                 U strcpy
000000000000013f T String_append
0000000000000000 T String_construct_d
000000000000004f T String_construct_s
00000000000000ce T String_deconstruct_d
00000000000000fa T String_deconstruct_s
0000000000000286 T String_empty
00000000000002e6 T String_find_after
000000000000025c T String_print
00000000000002a6 T String_touint
0000000000000093 T String_wrap_d
                 U strlen

eio.o:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U __imp___iob_func
                 U fgets
0000000000000000 T readline
                 U String_append
                 U String_construct
                 U String_empty
                 U strlen
```

I obviously don't understand linking as well as I thought, and I can't find anything on Google because I keep getting results about basic linking like my first working example.

Comment: Please update your post: 1) "dir" (or "ls -l") of your "j" library file 2) copy/paste the *exact* errrors

Comment: What do you see as the linking command from `make`?  You have a path to your compiler in the `makefile`; are you sure that's the same program you execute from the command line?  You're also linking an object file in the `makefile` but compiling the source file to object and then linking on the command line — what is the error message again?

Comment: @paulsm4 done, I wasn't quite sure what you meant by 1 though

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Astute. When I compile with the same exe as the path in the makefile I get other errors that I'll add to my question.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `$(objfiles)` by `$(srcfiles)` in the link command line?  The `paramSeed` warning isn't affecting the linking (but would if you add `-Werror` to your compiler options).  Is there any risk of a mix of 32-bit code in your program and 64-bit code in your library, or vice versa?  You'd often get a warning if that was an issue, but it would also prevent linking.

Comment: Okay, I feel like a dunce. @JonathanLeffler was right with the discrepancy in the paths. My path env variable finds gcc first in a haskell installation, which is 32 bit. However, when I was using my makefile, the gcc in my specified directory was 64 bit. GCC either ignored the library, or couldn't resolve the symbols because of a naming convention I suppose.

Comment: If you've not seen that sort of problem before, it is hard to diagnose.  Don't sweat it.  I've got to walk the dog, but I'll convert my comments into an answer after I get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

Before the question was elaborated with the exact error messages and the contents of the library:

> What do you see as the linking command from `make`? You have a path to your compiler in the `makefile`; are you sure that's the same program you execute from the command line? You're also linking an object file in the makefile but compiling the source file to object and then linking on the command line — what is the error message again?

Jon Weldon responded:

> When I compile with the same exe as the path in the makefile I get other errors that I'll add to my question.

Seeking further clarification, I asked:

> Does it work if you replace `$(objfiles)` by `$(srcfiles)` in the link command line? The `paramSeed` warning isn't affecting the linking (but would if you add `-Werror` to your compiler options). Is there any risk of a mix of 32-bit code in your program and 64-bit code in your library, or vice versa? You'd often get a warning if that was an issue, but it would also prevent linking.

And Jon Weldon responded:

> @JonathanLeffler was right with the discrepancy in the paths. My path env variable finds `gcc` first in a Haskell installation, which is 32 bit. However, when I was using my makefile, the `gcc` in my specified directory was 64 bit. GCC either ignored the library, or couldn't resolve the symbols because of a naming convention I suppose.

If you've not seen that sort of problem before, it is hard to diagnose.  However, the linker simply couldn't find any object files that contained the symbols in the right type of object file.  A warning about the wrong type of object files (or library as a whole) would have been nice, but ultimately it was correct — it couldn't find the right symbols.